# Font rendering problem on OSX+Chrome

Tags: bug, design

I've noticed that **bold** text looks a bit funny for me, and tested the site on Safari, and there it looks OK, so it's a Chrome-only issue (could be an OSX-Chrome-only AFAIK). I'm running Mavericks with all latest updates.

Haven't encountered this on any other sites, so I'm suspecting a problem with the webfonts.

Screenshots from [this page](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/62004/how-to-fix-google-play-store-update-error-in-android-4-0-4) below.

Chrome 32.0.1700.77:
[image: Chrome screenshot]

Safari 7.0.1:
[image: Safari screenshot]

Comment: Could that be a font issue in terms of different fonts used? First it reminds me a little of the [problems Flow had with the Roboto font](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/13086334#13086334), and second it looks like the Chrome example is minimally wider than the Safari one.

Comment: I tried changing the fonts one by one, and the problem seems to be 'DroidSansRegular', which is used by both browsers. There's also a MIME type mismatch when loading the webfont: `Resource interpreted as Font but transferred with MIME type font/x-woff: "http://cdn.sstatic.net/android/img/droidsans-webfont.woff".`

Comment: It looks a [little less funky](http://puu.sh/6zX3U.png) in Chrome on Windows, but there's still a little problem. Maybe it's chrome that don't like this MIME type, since the official MIME type for WOFF fonts is `application/font-woff`